# Rails construct or rewrite URL with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, routes

on my root page, I have an index action that lists everything from the images model.

in the index action there are 3 filters you can apply to the list that will only show whatever matches the filter criteria. These parameters show up in the URL like this when the select boxes are selected and filter is clicked:

```
http://localhost:3000/gender=m&height=62&weight=130
```

How can I make it so, the URL will rewrite to:

```
http://localhost:3000/m/62/130/
```

These values are attributes from the images model, stored in the gender, height and weight columns.
or, better yet, rewrite to something like this

```
http://localhost:3000/men/62-inches/130-lbs/
```

Here's what I tried, putting this in the routes:
match "/:gender/:height/:weight", :controller => "images", :action => "index", :conditions => { :method => :get }, via: 'get'

model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :gender, :measure_type, presence: true

  validates :image_location, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  validates :weight, length: {maximum: 3}



  has_attached_file :photo, styles: {

  small: '240x300'

  }

end
```

my routes.rb:

```
Images::Application.routes.draw do

     # match "/:gender/:height/:weight", :controller => "images", :action => "index", :conditions => { :method => :get }

     get 'images', to: redirect('/')

     match 'upload' => 'images#new',  :as => 'new_image_path',   via: 'get'

     match '/upload', :to => 'images#create', :via => :post, :as => :post_upload

     root "images#index"
 end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Images</h1>
  <%= form_tag root_path, method: :get do %>

  <%= select_tag "gender", options_for_select(["m", "w"], params[:gender]) %>

  <%= select_tag "height", options_for_select((60..70).to_a.map{|s| ["#{s} inches", s]}, selected: params[:height]), :prompt => "all" %>

  <%= select_tag "weight", options_for_select((100..300).step(5).to_a.map{|s| ["#{s} lbs", s]}, selected: params[:weight]), :prompt => "all" %>  

  <%= submit_tag 'Filter', name: nil %>

<% end %>

<table>

  <tr>

    <th>Gender</th>

    <th>Height</th>

    <th>Weight</th>

    <th>Image location</th>

  </tr>

<% @images.each do |image| %>

  <tr>

    <td><%= image.gender %></td>

    <td><%= image.height %></td>

    <td><%= image.weight %></td>

    <td><%= image.image_location %></td>


  </tr>

<% end %>

</table>
```

images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

   def index

     @images= Image.where(gender: params[:gender], height: params[:height], 

                                    weight: params[:weight])
   end
end
```

Update 1:

I'm starting to think it might involve doing something in the routes like   get '/', to: redirect('/params[gender]/params[height]/params[weight]')

Update 2:

I think I solved this, found the answer after hours searching in this post- [Ruby on Rails: How to redirect page based on post params in search_field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642138/ruby-on-rails-how-to-redirect-page-based-on-post-params-in-search-field)

Comment: and your current solution is giving you an error?

Comment: it does nothing, no error but the URL looks exactly the same as if that line didn't exist in my routes.

Comment: does the page reload when you click filter or are you doing it with ajax or something?

Comment: the page reloads when the filter button is clicked, which passes those params to the controller which sets the Images.where query to set the variable @images to whatever is returned from the model. no javascript or ajax involved.

Answer (score 0):

make the images route definition something like this

```
resources :images do    
  get "(gender/:gender)(/height/:height)(/weight/:weight)", :action => :index, :on => :collection
end
```